# Getting a specific row in excel sheet if my given target word found

Tags: excel

Can anybody help me for getting a row of a sheet that consists of my target searching word or string in sheet

for example my search word is 'active': there are 100 rows and at 50th row any columns in that row has word called 'active' then i need to retrieve that row ,i hope you understand my question

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Show us the function you tried

Comment: Thanks for joining the Stack Overflow Community! Please review [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Comment: record macro => manual search => stop recording => add `selection.row` :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this macro,

```
Sub searchWord()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, str As String, match As Boolean
match = False
str = InputBox("Enter string to be searched")
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 1 To Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If (InStr(Cells(i, j), str) > 0) Then
            Rows(i).Select
            match = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If match = True Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

This macro selects the row that has the string that you are searching for.

Comment: thanks for replying me, given logic works and even i want to know is there any direct chance of finding the value by using predefined methods in workbook or sheet like how we manually do in excel sheet on click crtl+f to find wanted string

Comment: other than ctrl+f there is no other way

Comment: you mean other then writing logic there is no other way

Comment: @sam Yes exactly